# Springframework 2.5.6 and OSGi

Tags: java, spring, osgi

I am trying to figure how to enable OSGi in a 2.5.6 install (The Dynamic Modules seems long gone now. Correct? ).

Is there some documentation describing the necessary steps and measures in getting OSGi workig the installed framework? I cannot find any. Maybe I'm just looking in the wrong places? I do get results that seem relevant with Google, but they point to dead ends (dead links - points to http://www.springsource.org/, but the documents seem to be removed).

I have a suite of OSGi bundles and need some of the services they provide as bean-references:
"<osgi:reference ... />" as defined by http://www.springframework.org/schem...pring-osgi.xsd 
Is this possible? Other ways to do it? Schema seems to still be in place. But valid?

Comment: Spring DM has been merged into [Gemini Blueprint project](http://www.eclipse.org/gemini/blueprint/documentation/) :

Answer (score 0):

I got some info from another source also indicating the fact that Spring DM merged into Eclipse Gemini Blueprint. As of version 3.0.0 of Spring framework this is valid.

Comment: so. is this your answer or are you still looking for a spring 2.5.6 solution?

Comment: We are looking into alternate solutions right now. Eventually, we will probably have to upgrade Spring framework.